# How to do this string pattern aaabbc to be displayed as 3a2b1c in java 8 using streams

Tags: java, java-8

I want to display the String pattern `aaabbcc` to be displayed as `3a2b2c` in java8 using streams

I have a working example in lower versions

```
String str = "aabbcccddd";

String chars[] = str.split("");
Map<String, Integer> compressMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
for(String s: chars) {
if("".equals(s))
    continue;
Integer count = compressMap.get(s);
if(count != null)
    compressMap.put(s, ++count);
else
    compressMap.put(s, 1);
}

StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : compressMap.entrySet()) {
    output.append(entry.getValue()).append(entry.getKey());
}
System.out.println(output);
```

can anyone help on this?

Comment: Help you with what?

Comment: Are we to assume that once a new character appears, the previous one is never seen again? I mean, do you want this code to work only for "aaabbcc" or would you like it to be applicable for strings like "abaaaccs" as well?

Comment: If you have a working example in lower versions, then it will also work in Java 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did will still work on Java 8, but you can simplify your code by relying on `Stream` as next:

```
String str = "aabbcccddd";
// Convert the String into a Stream
// Convert int into Character
// Group by Character and count occurrences
// For each entry add the key (Character) followed by the value (Occurrences) to the result
// using the joining collector
String output = str.chars()
    .mapToObj(i -> (char)i)
    .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, counting()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(entry -> Stream.of(entry.getValue().toString(), entry.getKey().toString()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());

System.out.println(output);
```

**Output:**

```
2a2b3c3d
```

Another approach slightly different where we convert `Integer` to `char` at the end:

```
String output = str.chars()
    .boxed()
    .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, counting()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(entry -> Stream.of(entry.getValue().toString(), Character.toString((char) entry.getKey().intValue())))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

**NB:** I use `LinkedHashMap::new` as supplier instead of the default `HashMap::new` to preserve the order.

Comment: I haven't voted on your answer yet. Still, your argument against me suggesting you shouldn't post answers to unclear questions shouldn't be to defend that good answers to bad questions shouldn't be downvoted. Those two things are unrelated. I want you to change your behavior to StackOverflow-first, me-later. Otherwise, StackOverflow will be overrun by garbage. (Not that this question is "garbage", but it definitely needs improvement to fit the standards.)

Comment: I always like to emphasize the 2nd to last part of [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): **Answer well-asked questions**.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I see, thx for the link and the clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

The other solution will be:

```
String output = Pattern.compile("(?<=(\\w))(?!\\1)")
        .splitAsStream(string)
        .map(part -> part.length() + part.substring(0, 1))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

The Pattern `(?<=(\\w))(?!\\1)` match places in String where next char is different than previous, so it split String into parts containing separate letters, then map it to string with its length.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for above problem:
Time complexity: O(n)
Space complexity: O(1)

```
    private void printCharacterLength(char[] arr) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
            count++;
        } else {
            result.append((count > 1 ? count : "")).append(arr[i - 1]);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    result.append((count > 1 ? count : "")).append(arr[arr.length - 1]);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```